Is possible use vue3/vite components ou vue2/vite project?
Recently we start a upgrade in our system, made using vue2 and we upgrade to vue3, both using vite, but the system is on production and we can't just turn off and make the upgrade/refactor. The solution that we think is implement a microfrontend with vue3, spliting the current system in modules, and plug these remote modules on current vue2 system. When all modules are finished, we just change the 'hub/host' vue2 system to a new host made with vue3 too.
But when i import the component appears a internal error in moment of render.
that's the configuration of vite on remote project (vue3):
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    target: 'esnext',
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    federation({
      name: 'teste',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './TesteApp': './src/App.vue',
      },
      shared: {
        vue: {
          singleton: true,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  server: {
    port: 4173,
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
      methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})

and that's the configuration of vite on vue2/host project:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue2 from "@vitejs/plugin-vue2";
import { VuetifyResolver } from "unplugin-vue-components/resolvers";
import Components from "unplugin-vue-components/vite";
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url"
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation'

export default defineConfig({

  plugins: [
    vue2(),
    Components({
      resolvers: [
        VuetifyResolver(),
      ],
      exclude: [/vue-tour/],
    }),
    federation({
      name: 'meu-teste',
      remotes: {
          teste: 'http://localhost:4173/assets/remoteEntry.js',
      },
      shared: {
        vue: {
          singleton: true,
        },
      }
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
      extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.json', '.vue', '.scss'],
    },
  },
  server: {
    port: 8080,
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
      methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    },
  },
})

and finally, the vue2 component where i import the remote:
<template>
  <div class="width-100 height-100">
    haha
    <component :is="asyncComponent" v-if="asyncComponent"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";

export default {
  name: 'TesteHubView',
  data() {
    return {
      asyncComponent: null,
    };
  },
  async created() {
    const TesteApp = await defineAsyncComponent(() => import("teste/TesteApp"));
    this.asyncComponent = TesteApp;
  },
};
</script>

but i keep getting that error:
TesteView.vue:47 TypeError: Nn is not a function
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (__federation_expose_…DzeVP1ms.js:5:24040)
    at Vue2._render (chunk-W4PLFPYA.js?v=7508ef34:1657:22)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (chunk-W4PLFPYA.js?v=7508ef34:2374:21)
    at Watcher2.get (chunk-W4PLFPYA.js?v=7508ef34:5981:31)
    at new Watcher2 (chunk-W4PLFPYA.js?v=7508ef34:5974:48)
    at mountComponent (chunk-W4PLFPYA.js?v=7508ef34:2392:3)
    at Vue.$mount (chunk-W4PLFPYA.js?v=7508ef34:7032:14)
    at init (chunk-W4PLFPYA.js?v=7508ef34:6132:17)
    at createComponent2 (chunk-W4PLFPYA.js?v=7508ef34:4066:9)
    at createElm (chunk-W4PLFPYA.js?v=7508ef34:4028:9)

and if i enter on file to see what is that, it's on last part of the file, on start of rendering (i'll show a piece of code of that part):
...
, $n = xn({
    __name: "App",
    setup(e) {
        return (t, n) => (Nn(),
        Mn(On, null, [re("header", null, [n[2] || (n[2] = re("img", {
            alt: "Vue logo",
            class: "logo",
            src: pt,
            width: "125",
            height: "125"
        }, null, -1)), re("div", In, [oe(An, {
            msg: "You did it!"
        }), re("nav", null, [oe(ve(we), {
            to: "/"
        }, {
            default: We( () => n[0] || (n[0] = [Ue("Home")])),
            _: 1
        }), oe(ve(we), {
            to: "/about"
        }, {
            default: We( () => n[1] || (n[1] = [Ue("About")])),
            _: 1
        })])])]), oe(ve(lt))], 64))
    }
})
...

i ask for help: this is even truly possible? what i made wrong? or just works if the versions of libs are the same? please help me

You can't import v3 comps in v2 and expect them to work. It would be the same if you tried to use vue and react on the same page. React component isn't a "component" to Vue but some random thing from the outside world. Treat them as different frameworks. Mount a sub-app to a container, etc.
